# How to custom import selected columns from file in GCS into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, python-import

I'm trying to custom import selected columns from file in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) into BigQuery because there are columns with syntax issues that are causing import error into BigQuery. Thus I want to exclude some specific columns from importing into BigQuery.

I have been using `GCSToBigQueryOperator` to import files from GCS into BigQuery. I tried to specify the schema_fields, but it seems like it doesn't work that way. Are there other Airflow operators or other ways to import only selected columns from GCS to BigQuery?

Comment: The easiest way is to import the file completely and then to run a query that select only the required column. But I understand that the other column are broken. Thefore, you have to pre process the file, with the system of your choice, and then to load the result in BigQuery. There is no option in BigQuery to skip some columns

Comment: Agree with Guillaume with the fact that the best is to pre process the data to have more control. However, if you are uploading a JSON file, you can use the option --ignore_unknown_values.  The same flag also works with CSV but it will ignore the trailing columns

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions to do that with `Airflow`.
If you want only to skip extra fields, you can set the param `ignore_unknown_values` as `True` in the `GCSToBigQueryOperator`.
For more complex logics and the need to apply specific transformations, I propose you 2 solutions :

#### Solution 1

- Use a staging table containing the Raw data
- Truncate the staging table (option WRITE_TRUNCATE)
- Insert the file to this staging table with `GCSToBigQueryOperator`
- Use a `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` to select only the needed fields, apply your transformations with `SQL` and insert them to the final table

Example :

```py
import airflow
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator

with airflow.DAG(
        "dag_id",
        default_args={},
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    load_file_to_staging_table = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_file_to_staging_table',
        bucket="source_bucket",
        source_objects=[f'folder/*.json'],
        destination_project_dataset_table='project:dataset.staging_table',
        source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        compression=None,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        autodetect=True
    )

    insert_final_table_query = """
            SELECT 
                field1,
                field1
                ....
            FROM `project.dataset.staging_table`
    """

    insert_to_final_table = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='insert_to_final_table',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": insert_final_table_query,
                "useLegacySql": False,
                'destinationTable': {
                    'projectId': "project",
                    'datasetId': "dataset",
                    'tableId': "final_table"
                },
            }
        },
        location='EU'
    )

    load_file_to_staging_table >> insert_to_final_table
```

For the `SQL` queries, I volontary proposed them in the `Python` code for simplicity, but you can also use `.sql` file + `Jinja` template for a more elegant solution.

#### Solution 2

- Use a `PythonOperator`
- In this operator, use the `Cloud Storage` `Python` client to retrieve file data in a list of `Dict`
- Apply tne needed transformations on `Python` on the list of `Dict`
- Use the `BigQuery` `Python` client to save data to the `BigQuery` table

```py
import json
from typing import List, Dict

import airflow
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from google.cloud import bigquery


def insert_file_to_bq(dataset, table):
    file_data: List[Dict] = read_file_data_from_gcs()
    
    # Apply your transformation in the list of Dict.

    client = bigquery.Client()
    client.insert_rows_json(f'{dataset}.{table}', file_data)


def read_file_data_from_gcs():
    from google.cloud import storage

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('test_bucket')

    blob = bucket.get_blob('temp_files_folder/test.json')
    result_bytes = blob.download_as_bytes()

    return json.loads(result_bytes.decode('utf-8'))


with airflow.DAG(
        "dag_id",
        default_args={},
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    start_dag = DummyOperator(task_id='OK', dag=dag)

    insert_file_to_bq_table = PythonOperator(
        task_id="save_file_bq",
        op_kwargs={
            'dataset': 'dataset',
            'table': 'table'
        },
        python_callable=insert_file_to_bq
    )

    start_dag >> insert_file_to_bq_table
```